# How the detail view controller told the main controller about the changes made?

Tags: object, uinavigationcontroller

I'm reading the Big Nerd Ranch book and I'm at the 10th chapter about the navigation controller.

In the main controller, there is a TableView ( https://github.com/bignerdranch/iOS3eSolutions/blob/master/11.%20Homepwner/Homepwner/Homepwner/ItemsViewController.m ) where there are two methods that interact with the detail view :

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[self tableView] reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView 
    didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

    NSArray *items = [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
    BNRItem *selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    // Give detail view controller a pointer to the item object in row
    [detailViewController setItem:selectedItem];

    // Push it onto the top of the navigation controller's stack
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController
                                           animated:YES];
}
```

In the detail view controller (https://github.com/bignerdranch/iOS3eSolutions/blob/master/11.%20Homepwner/Homepwner/Homepwner/DetailViewController.m), there is a method that "saves" the `BNRItem` being changed :

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    // Clear first responder
    [[self view] endEditing:YES];

    // "Save" changes to item
    [item setItemName:[nameField text]];
    [item setSerialNumber:[serialNumberField text]];
    [item setValueInDollars:[[valueField text] intValue]];
}
```

The code works well : 
I understand how the main controller set the object to edit but I don't understand how the main view controller knows that the `BNRItem` has been changed and then set it back to the tableview ?

I was excepting the author to write a setter in the main controller (ItemsViewController.m ) that could be called by the detail view controller (DetailViewController.m) giving the new `BNRItem`. 
But this part works "automatically".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are pointing to the same memory chunk in both controllers, changed made in the `DetailViewController` are obviously reported in `ItemsViewController.m`.